# Is my translation of 一般 within 神秘的 “磁帶” 如程序加載到計算機一般植入人的大腦中 correct?

Tags: translation

Original:

In the science fiction books I read as a kid, reading had often been replaced by some more efficient way of acquiring knowledge. Mysterious "tapes" would load it into one's brain like a program being loaded into a computer.

Translation:
在我小時候讀的科幻小說中，總有比閱讀更有效率的方式獲取知識，神秘的 “磁帶” 如程序加載到計算機一般植入人的大腦中。

Source: https://catcoding.me/p/read/

I was trying to dissect the second sentence, to me it reads like:

Mysterious "tapes" like (如) program load into computer the same (一般) load into human brain.

Is my understanding of 如 and 一般 correct here?

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct.  如...一般 = 就像是....一樣 = like(ly)....the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[如 XX 一般] = [like XX] is a common Chinese grammar structure. It is redundant to put "the same as" in the English translation when you already have "like" in it

> 神秘的 “磁帶”[**如**][*程序加載到計算機*][**一般**]植入人的大腦中。

> Mysterious "tapes" implants information into the human brain, [**like**] [*loading programs into a computer*]

Answer (score 2):

如。。。。一般………is equivalent to the structure in English “the same……as….” Or “as……..as” or simply “as” or “just as”.

神秘的 “磁帶” 如程序加載到計算機一般植入人的大腦中。could be translated as “the mysterious “tape” was planted into the brain of a man the same way/just as downloading a software into a computer.

Answer (score 1):

A common structure in Chinese, you can find many examples. Chinese likes to wrap things around phrases.

如你一般的美好。
As beautiful as you!

这必须如芭蕾舞一般完成。
This needs to be done as ballet.

他的精力、热诚和好奇心如毯子一般将你包围。
His energy, enthusiasm and curiosity envelope you like a blanket.

Answer (score 0):

I consider that the original sentence is not correct. A key grammar component was missing.

在我小時候讀的科幻小說中，總有比閱讀更有效率的方式獲取知識，神秘的 “磁帶” 如程序加載到計算機一般植入人的大腦中。

It should be corrected as：

神秘的 “磁帶” 如程序加載到計算機一般**把知识**植入人的大腦中。

The translation would be:

Just as the way that a tape loads the program into a computer, a mysterious "tape" could load knowledge into the human brain.

We know that it is not to load the "type" into the brain.